Exercise regarding conditional expectation
Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent $B(1,p)$ random variables and $Y:=X_1+...+X_n$.
a) What is the conditional distribution of $X_1$ assuming $Y=k$ ($0 \leq k \leq n$)?
b) Determine the conditional expectation
$E[X_1|Y]$!
Appraoch:
I was able to do part 1).  I did get $P(X_1=1|Y=k)=\frac{k}{n}$.
Regarding part b):
To solve b) I thought about using the following formula:
$E[X_1|Y]=\sum_y E[X_1|Y=y] 1_{Y=y}$
In this specific case, this would be: $E[X_1|Y]=\sum_{k=1}^n E[X_1|Y=k] 1_{Y=k}$
So it comes down to calcuating E[X|Y=k] (i.e. part a of the exercise):
$E[X|Y=k]=\sum_{x \in R_X}\frac{P(X=x,Y=k)}{P(Y=k)}=0 \cdot \frac{P(X=0,Y=k)}{P(Y=k)} + 1 \cdot \frac{P(X=1,Y=k)}{P(Y=k)}$
Then I did rewrite $Y=X_1+...+X_n=k$ to $X_2+...+X_n=k-1$ and since $X_1$ and $X_2+...+X_n$ are independent:
$\frac{P(X=1,X_2+...+X_n=k-1)}{P(Y=k)}= \frac{p \cdot \binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1} (1-p)^{n-k}}{\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}}=\frac{k}{n}$.
Thus I get $E[X_1|Y]=\sum_{k=1}^n E[X_1|Y=k] 1_{Y=k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} 1_{Y=k}$.
This means $E[X_1|Y]$ has the values
$E[X_1|Y]=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{n} & \text{with probability } P(Y=1) \\
         \frac{2}{n} & \text{with probability } P(Y=2) \\
. \\
. \\
.\\
\frac{n}{n} & \text{with probability } P(Y=n)
\end{array}
 \right.$
But the solution of this exercise states that the result is $E[X_1|Y]=\frac{Y}{n}$.
Where is my mistake (and how do I get the correct result)?

There is no mistake. Your result $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} 1_{Y=k}$ is the same as the expansion of $\frac Yn$ into the indicator functions of its level sets.

@KurtG. What are level sets? Could you please explain how both results are the same?

$Y$ takes values only in ${1,...,n}.$ The level sets are ${\omega\in\Omega:Y(\omega)=k}.$ Please proceed.

@KurtG. Could you tell me if this is correct? To show that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n}1_{Y=k}=\frac{Y}{n}$, let $k \in {1,...,n}$ arbitraty, we consider $\omega \in Y^{-1}({k})$, then $k \cdot 1_{Y=k}(\omega)=k \cdot 1= k = Y(\omega)$. If $\omega \notin Y^{-1}({k})$, then both sides are equal to $0$.

Is correct. $\phantom.$

Thank you very much!


Where is my mistake (and how do I get the correct result)?

It is not "with probability" it is "when" (ie "in the event of", or "if").
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf E[X_1\mid Y]&=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & \text{when } Y=1 \\
         \frac{2}{n} & \text{when } Y=2 \\
~\vdots \\
\frac{n}{n} & \text{when } Y=n
\end{cases}
\\[2ex] &= Y/n &&\text{since }Y\in[[1, n]]\end{align}$
